# Scanner needs inputs twice before continuing

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Hey guys i have got a small weird problem here, i am asking the user to input their menu choice and depending on what they choose it calls a certain method.

I have used scanner.next() after some googling but for some reason only when i enter 1 or 2, i press enter and then press say 1 again and then it actually works. But what is weird that it calls options 3, 4, 5 and 6, immediately without me having to input the number twice.

I have tried with scanner.nextLine() after the scanner.nextInt() and that just leaves me having to put my option 1 or 2 in with no result.

```
while(exit == 0)
    {

            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("Menu 1: Display fullname of the user \n");
            System.out.println("Menu 2: Display of user information \n");
            System.out.println("Menu 3: Change password \n");
            System.out.println("Menu 4: List all of users in the library full name\n");
            System.out.println("Menu 5: Search for a book\n");
            System.out.println("Press 6 to search for a books location in the library\n");
            System.out.println("Press 0 to exit\n");

            System.out.println("Enter choice: ");
            int menuChoice = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.next();


                     if(menuChoice == 1)
                    {
                        displayUserFullName();
                    }
                    else if(menuChoice == 2)
                    {
                        displayUserInformation();
                    }

                    else if(menuChoice == 3)
                    {
                        menuForChangePassword();
                    }

                    else if(menuChoice == 4)
                    {
                        displayAllUserInSystem();
                    }
                    else if(menuChoice == 5)
                    {
                        searchBookByISBN();
                    }
                    else if(menuChoice == 6)
                    {
                        searchBookLocation();
                    }
                    else if(menuChoice == 0)
                    {
                        exit = 1;
                    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

```
int menuChoice = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.next();
```

Read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) for scanner. It waits for user input:

> public String next(): [..] This method may block while waiting for input to scan

So in your program, you say: wait for user to type and int, then wait for user to type something.

Remove the `scanner.next();` and it should work.

Comment: i type in 1 or 2 it just disappears when i press enter and then i type it in again etc, it never progresses. That is if i remove scanner.next().

Comment: `it never progresses`, that's a good time to learn how to use a debugger. Input should be ok, check the called methods.

Comment: I checked. It should work if you remove the `scanner.next();`.
Maybe you have trouble in your method `displayUserFullName()`.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner is a class parsing single tokens, like `nextInt`, `nextDouble`, `nextToken` (String). With corresponding testing methods: `hasNextInt` and so on.
All this parsing you do not need, so use `nextLine` for an entered line, or an other Reader class (InputStreamReader, BufferedReader).

Also you may utilize `switch` instead of `if else if`.

```
       String menuChoice = scanner.nextLine();
       switch (menuChoice) {
       case "1":
           displayUserFullName();
           break;
       case "2":
           displayUserInformation();
           break;
       case "3":
           menuForChangePassword();
           break;
       case "4":
           displayAllUserInSystem();
           break;
       case "5":
           searchBookByISBN();
            break;
       case "6":
           searchBookLocation();
           break;
       case "0":
           exit = 1;
           break;
       default:
           System.out.printf("Unknown choice: '%s'%n", menuChoice);
       }
```

`menuChoice` will contain the entire line, without line ending.

You might use an int with `Integer.parseInt(menuChoice)` but this would throw a `NumberFormatException` on wrong input, aborting your program. `Scanner.nextInt` would hang too, actually needing an `hasNextInt()`.